# Custom View to Bitmap gives low quality

Tags: android, kotlin, pdf, bitmap, itext7

I am running into some problems and can't find a proper solution. I am using Android Studio with Kotlin.

My main goal is to generate a PDF file. In this PDF file I want to show some line charts. I do use these chart in the app itself and this works fine. Bit by bit I get closer to the answer but I am stuck in the final fase for day's now.

I have build a chart image in PaintCode. PaintCode gives a Java file output, with a Custom View I can show this image in a View and change the image with parameters. The beauty is that is Vector style and size independent.

In a perfect world I would like to directly draw a new chart into the PDF file, that way I can draw any chart no matter what kind of chart is shown on the display. But as far as I got it right, I have to transform the 'real' View to a bitmap before I can implement it inside my PDF file. Again it is not the way I would like but I got this working. But two problems remain.

1. my actual chart image on screen disappears. Not ideal again but I can coop with that.
2. the main issue, the quality of the chart is really bad.

I search the internet a lot and found lots of post on real images to PDF or to Bitmap, or low quality Bitmap out of camera images. But I'm not able to implement those suggestions because the situatie is a bit different.

This is a sample output from Paintcode:

```
package com.example.project;

    import android.graphics.Paint;
    import android.graphics.Matrix;
    import android.graphics.RectF;
    import android.graphics.Canvas;
    import android.graphics.Color;
    import android.graphics.Path;
    import java.util.Stack;
    public class StyleKitName {


// Resizing Behavior
public enum ResizingBehavior {
    AspectFit, //!< The content is proportionally resized to fit into the target rectangle.
    AspectFill, //!< The content is proportionally resized to completely fill the target rectangle.
    Stretch, //!< The content is stretched to match the entire target rectangle.
    Center, //!< The content is centered in the target rectangle, but it is NOT resized.
}

// Canvas Drawings
// Tab

private static class CacheForCanvas1 {
    private static Paint paint = new Paint();
    private static RectF originalFrame = new RectF(0f, 0f, 358f, 358f);
    private static RectF resizedFrame = new RectF();
    private static RectF ovalRect = new RectF();
    private static Path ovalPath = new Path();
}

public static void drawCanvas1(Canvas canvas, float fraction, float angle) {
    StyleKitName.drawCanvas1(canvas, new RectF(0f, 0f, 358f, 358f), ResizingBehavior.AspectFit, fraction, angle);
}

public static void drawCanvas1(Canvas canvas, RectF targetFrame, ResizingBehavior resizing, float fraction, float angle) {
    // General Declarations
    Stack<Matrix> currentTransformation = new Stack<Matrix>();
    currentTransformation.push(new Matrix());
    Paint paint = CacheForCanvas1.paint;
    
    // Local Variables
    float expression = 348f * fraction;
    
    // Resize to Target Frame
    canvas.save();
    RectF resizedFrame = CacheForCanvas1.resizedFrame;
    StyleKitName.resizingBehaviorApply(resizing, CacheForCanvas1.originalFrame, targetFrame, resizedFrame);
    canvas.translate(resizedFrame.left, resizedFrame.top);
    canvas.scale(resizedFrame.width() / 358f, resizedFrame.height() / 358f);
    
    // Oval
    canvas.save();
    canvas.translate(179f, 179f);
    currentTransformation.peek().postTranslate(179f, 179f);
    canvas.rotate(-angle);
    currentTransformation.peek().postRotate(-angle);
    RectF ovalRect = CacheForCanvas1.ovalRect;
    ovalRect.set(-174f, -174f, expression - 174f, 174f);
    Path ovalPath = CacheForCanvas1.ovalPath;
    ovalPath.reset();
    ovalPath.addOval(ovalRect, Path.Direction.CW);
    
    paint.reset();
    paint.setFlags(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG);
    paint.setStrokeWidth(10f);
    paint.setStrokeMiter(10f);
    canvas.save();
    paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
    paint.setColor(Color.DKGRAY);
    canvas.drawPath(ovalPath, paint);
    canvas.restore();
    canvas.restore();
    
    canvas.restore();
}


// Resizing Behavior
public static void resizingBehaviorApply(ResizingBehavior behavior, RectF rect, RectF target, RectF result) {
    if (rect.equals(target) || target == null) {
        result.set(rect);
        return;
    }
    
    if (behavior == ResizingBehavior.Stretch) {
        result.set(target);
        return;
    }
    
    float xRatio = Math.abs(target.width() / rect.width());
    float yRatio = Math.abs(target.height() / rect.height());
    float scale = 0f;
    
    switch (behavior) {
        case AspectFit: {
            scale = Math.min(xRatio, yRatio);
            break;
        }
        case AspectFill: {
            scale = Math.max(xRatio, yRatio);
            break;
        }
        case Center: {
            scale = 1f;
            break;
        }
    }
    
    float newWidth = Math.abs(rect.width() * scale);
    float newHeight = Math.abs(rect.height() * scale);
    result.set(target.centerX() - newWidth / 2,
        target.centerY() - newHeight / 2,
        target.centerX() + newWidth / 2,
        target.centerY() + newHeight / 2);
}


    }
```

This is my custom view sample:

```
    package com.brains2success.testpdfcreate

    import android.content.Context
    import android.graphics.*
    import android.graphics.drawable.Drawable
    import android.text.TextPaint
    import android.util.AttributeSet
    import android.view.View
    import androidx.appcompat.widget.LinearLayoutCompat

    class HeaderView : View {

constructor(context: Context) : super(context) {
    init(null, 0)
}

constructor(context: Context, attrs: AttributeSet) : super(context, attrs) {
    init(attrs, 0)
}

constructor(context: Context, attrs: AttributeSet, defStyle: Int) : super(
    context,
    attrs,
    defStyle
) {
    init(attrs, defStyle)
}

private fun init(attrs: AttributeSet?, defStyle: Int) {
    // Load attributes
    val a = context.obtainStyledAttributes(
        attrs, R.styleable.HeaderView, defStyle, 0
    )

    a.recycle()
}

override fun onDraw(canvas: Canvas) {
    super.onDraw(canvas)
    StyleKitName.drawCanvas1(
        canvas,
        RectF(0f, 0f, width.toFloat(), height.toFloat()),
        StyleKitName.ResizingBehavior.AspectFit,
        0.8f,
        145f
    )
}
    }
```

This is the function to cast the View to bitmap:

```
fun createBitmapFromView(view: View, width: Int, height: Int): Bitmap {
    view.layoutParams = ConstraintLayout.LayoutParams(
        ConstraintLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
        ConstraintLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT
    )

    view.measure(
        View.MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(width, View.MeasureSpec.EXACTLY),
        View.MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(height, View.MeasureSpec.EXACTLY)
    )

    view.layout(0, 0, width, height)  // this one makes my chart on screen dissapear, but without this line i got no chart on the PDF file.

    val canvas = Canvas()
    val bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(width, height, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888)
    canvas.setBitmap(bitmap)
    view.draw(canvas)

    return bitmap
}
```

And finally the function to generate the PDF file (with itext 7)

```
private fun createPDF2() {
    val FILE_PRINT: String = "PDFprint.pdf"
    val pdfPath = filesDir.absolutePath
    val file = File(pdfPath, FILE_PRINT)
    FileOutputStream(file)

    val writer = PdfWriter(file)
    val pdfDocument = PdfDocument(writer)
    val document = Document(pdfDocument)

    pdfDocument.setDefaultPageSize(PageSize.A4)
    document.setMargins(0f,0f,0f,0f)

    var bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(resources, R.drawable.pdfb)
    var stream = ByteArrayOutputStream()
    bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, stream)
    var bitmapData = stream.toByteArray()
    var imageData = ImageDataFactory.create(bitmapData)
    var image = Image(imageData)
    document.add(image)

    val sizeHeight = pdfDocument.getPage(1).pageSize.height
    val sizeWidth = pdfDocument.getPage(1).pageSize.width

    bitmap = createBitmapFromView(header,(sizeWidth * 0.9).toInt(),37)
    stream = ByteArrayOutputStream()
    bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, stream)
    bitmapData = stream.toByteArray()
    imageData = ImageDataFactory.create(bitmapData)
    image = Image(imageData)
    image.setFixedPosition(1, (sizeWidth - (sizeWidth * 0.9f)) / 2f, (sizeHeight - 180f) - 37f, (sizeWidth * 0.9f))
    document.add(image)

    document.close()
}
```

I hope some can help me get in the right direction.

Comment: Like you said "iText should accept raw line or shape vector" So my goal is to use the Custom View Class to draw directly into the PDF. I got the feeling that i'am not far off, but I just can't wrap my finger around it.

If try to make a VAR with: StyleKitName.drawCanvas1(
canvas,
RectF(0f, 0f, width.toFloat(), height.toFloat()),
StyleKitName.ResizingBehavior.AspectFit,
0.8f,
145f)
And try to add that to the PDF it won't work